# Testing web service deployment with Arquillian: context root is null

Tags: glassfish, jboss-arquillian

I want to deploy an enterprise application with a web service facade to glassfish with Arquillian. I am not very experienced in this thema.

I send the WebService and Interface codes with annotiations.

WebService Implementation:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ena.access.ticketsservices.facade.ITicketsRoleMappingsFacade")
@DeclareRoles({ "User", "Guest", "ProjectAdmin", "Admin" })
public class TicketsRoleMappingsFacade implements ITicketsRoleMappingsFacade {
 ...
}
```

Interface:

```
@WebService(name = "TicketsRoleMappingsFacade")
public interface ITicketsRoleMappingsFacade {

  @WebMethod
  @WebResult(name = "createProjectResult")
  public Project createProject(@WebParam(name = "createproject") Project project);          
}
```

And the following xml files are glassfish configuration files.

application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application
    version="6"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd">

    <display-name>j2ee-ear</display-name>

    <module>
        <ejb>j2ee-ejb.jar</ejb>
    </module>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>User</role-name>        
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>Guest</role-name>        
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>ProjectAdmin</role-name>        
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>        
    </security-role>

    <library-directory>lib</library-directory>

</application>
```

glassfish-application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-application PUBLIC -//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Java EE Application 6.0//EN http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-application_6_0-1.dtd>
<glassfish-application>

    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
        <group-name>User</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>Guest</role-name>
        <group-name>Guest</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>ProjectAdmin</role-name>
        <group-name>ProjectAdmin</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
        <group-name>Admin</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <realm>someRealm</realm>
</glassfish-application>
```

glassfish-ejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-ejb-jar PUBLIC -//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 EJB 3.1//EN http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-ejb-jar_3_1-1.dtd>
<glassfish-ejb-jar>

    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>User</role-name>
        <group-name>User</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>Guest</role-name>
        <group-name>Guest</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>ProjectAdmin</role-name>
        <group-name>ProjectAdmin</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>Admin</role-name>
        <group-name>Admin</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <ejb>
            <ejb-name>TicketsRoleMappingsFacade</ejb-name>
            <webservice-endpoint>
                <port-component-name>TicketsRoleMappingsFacade</port-component-name>
                <port-component-uri>/TicketsRoleMappingsFacade</port-component-uri>
            </webservice-endpoint>
        </ejb>
    </enterprise-beans>

</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

When I build ear file with ShrinkWrap and deploy  get the following lines in log servers log, so I think a part of deployment was succesfull:

```
[#|2013-08-03T17:23:57.322+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.webservices.org.glassfish.webservices|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WS00019: EJB Endpoint deployed j2ee-ear  listening at address at http://localhost:9999/TicketsRoleMappingsFacadeService/TicketsRoleMappingsFacade|#]
```

But I also get the following exception in Arquillian:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contextRoot must not be null
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.protocol.metadata.Servlet.<init>(Servlet.java:48)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.clientutils.GlassFishClientService.resolveWebModuleSubComponents(GlassFishClientService.java:357)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.clientutils.GlassFishClientService.doDeploy(GlassFishClientService.java:227)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.CommonGlassFishManager.deploy(CommonGlassFishManager.java:101)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.glassfish.remote_3_1.GlassFishRestDeployableContainer.deploy(GlassFishRestDeployableContainer.java:71)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:161)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:128)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:271)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at 
....
```

I don't have any .war file for this test setup how can I specify the contextRoot for my web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 8 years, it is nice to remember the problems of my master thesis...
As far as I remember there was no problem with the code above, but there was a bug in the old Arquillian version.

After a few weeks, my supervisor returned from holiday and just updated the Arquillian version in the parent project and tests started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a WAR(web application) you theoretically would not need the application.xml. My suggestion, try to delete it.

The successful deployment of the application in glassfish does not mean it will work in Arquillian. Arquillian has some issues with file name and context-root (I had this issue with an WAR file)

An EAR, according to [JavaEE 6 Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html), usually is used to bind WARs and EJBs. So, in theory, if you do not have a WAR you don't exactly need an EAR. You can deploy the EJB directly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Cladio, you should edit out your mention of wanting to comment and the end part about ignoring you.  You believe your changes may answer his issue, that qualifies as being worth an answer. Comments are for asking for clarification. For instance, if you asked "Have you tried deleting your application.xml" that would be better suited as a comment. It just takes a couple useful answers or questions before you can comment.